# Possible to make slug generation turn "&" to "and" for url? as extension/plugin/patch?

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, url

I have a lot of clients who like to write "&" in their titles but the slug auto generation removes the "& " which can give the url a totally different meaning and so we must hand check them.

Is an override or patch or something possible to change this so that & becomes "and" ?

```
Title: House & Boat
e.g. http://www.domain.com/sections/house-boat
vs http://www.domain.com/sections/house-and-boat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to override that. In the end it uses `JFilterOutput::stringURLUnicodeSlug()` or `JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe()` (depending on the global setting) to make the alias URL safe. Since `&` isn't a valid character in an URL it is stripped and replaced with a `-`.

So you had to override a core class, which isn't recommended at all.

The easier way is probably to create a plugin which runs during or after the save process and generates a new alias.
I don't know if there is an existing one, but I think it should be possible to create such a plugin.

Or you can teach your users to make sure the alias is fine :-)

Comment: I believe you meant "save process" not "safe process"

Comment: Ok Just needed the pointer to if it was possible without a core hack as could just add one line to the stringURLSafe function where it replaces spaces.

Comment: Indeed save, not safe :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than teach users to monitor the alias, teach users/admins to write the titles without the ampersand to begin with.  Tell them it will "break the site" if necessary, wink wink.

Comment: I have done that tactic before for file names, and other things but wanted to see a technical solution as could be possible.

Comment: I tell them no spaces and caps in images dir and names and they still do it ! Have to have a virtual slap on the wrist button or a "No, No, NO..." Jurassic Park Gif ;)